# windows media player state wont change

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

I m trying to make it so that when a song finishes the next one plays automatically.I am loading the names of the songs in a listbox and i also have a dictionary SongsNPaths in which the keys contain the name of the songs and the values their full path.I also have a play button and its use is to play a song after it has been paused.Also a song will play when i click on its name inside the listbox.Everything works as intended when i do it manually however when i try to get a song to play after the previous ended it wont.Even though i change the listboxes index nothing happens and the WMP state is stack at Ready.Also even though the index changes and nothing happens the WMP url gets updated since if i manually push the play button the song starts normally.Any ideas on what i m missing?

 
code:
The play button:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //elexgei an exei klikaristei idi mia fora to button wste na min dinei sunexws to path kai to tragoudi na xekinaei apo tin arxi

            if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {

                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            }
        }
```

Event whenever the listbox selected value is changed:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {

                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = SongsNPaths[listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()];
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            }
        }
```

Event after a song ended:

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
        {//check to state to WMP an einai finished ---> 8 to allazei tragoudi (bazei to epomeno)

            if(e.newState == 8)
            {
                if(listBox1.Items.Count > 1)
                {
                    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != listBox1.Items.Count - 1)
                    {
                        listBox1.SelectedIndex++;

                        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = SongsNPaths[listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()];

                        //button2.PerformClick();

                        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();


                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should help you.

```
if(e.newState == 8)
{
   if(listBox1.Items.Count > 1)
   {
         if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != listBox1.Items.Count - 1)
         {
               listBox1.SelectedIndex++;
               axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = SongsNPaths[listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()];

               this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = newFilePath;
            }));
         }
   }
}
```

If you check the documentation of [AxWindowsMediaPlayer.Url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WMP/axwmplib-axwindowsmediaplayer-url--vb-and-c) property, it is not advisable to call this property directly from the event handler.

> Do not call this method from event handler code. Calling URL from an
>   event handler may yield unexpected results.

One option would be as described in code above.